# Question about pathname encoding

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8, pathname

What have I done to get such a strange encoding in this path-name?
In my file manager (Dolphin) the path-name looks good.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
use File::Find;
use Devel::Peek;
use Encode qw(decode);

my $string;
find( sub { $string = $File::Find::name }, 'Delibes, Léo' );
$string =~ s|Delibes,\ ||;
$string =~ s|\..*\z||;
my ( $s1, $s2 ) = split m|/|, $string, 2;

say Dump $s1;
say Dump $s2;

# SV = PV(0x824b50) at 0x9346d8
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
#   PV = 0x93da30 "L\303\251o"\0 [UTF8 "L\x{e9}o"]
#   CUR = 4
#   LEN = 16

# SV = PV(0x7a7150) at 0x934c30
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
#   PV = 0x7781e0 "Lakm\303\203\302\251"\0 [UTF8 "Lakm\x{c3}\x{a9}"]
#   CUR = 8
#   LEN = 16

say $s1;
say $s2;

# Léo
# LakmÃ©

$s1 = decode( 'utf-8', $s1 );
$s2 = decode( 'utf-8', $s2 );

say $s1;
say $s2;

# L�o
# Lakmé
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately your operating system's pathname API is another "binary interface" where you will have to use `Encode::encode` and `Encode::decode` to get predictable results.

Most operating systems treat pathnames as a sequence of octets (i.e. bytes). Whether that sequence should be interpreted as latin-1, UTF-8 or other character encoding is an application decision. Consequently the value returned by `readdir()` is simply a sequence of octets, and `File::Find` doesn't know that you want the path name as Unicode code points. It forms `$File::Find::name` by simply concatenating the directory path (which you supplied) with the value returned by your OS via `readdir()`, and that's how you got code points mashed with octets.

Rule of thumb: Whenever passing path names to the OS, `Encode::encode()` it to make sure it is a sequence of octets. When getting a path name from the OS, `Encode::decode()` it to the character set  that your application wants it in.

You can make your program work by calling `find` this way:

```
find( sub { ... }, Encode::encode('utf8', 'Delibes, Léo') );
```

And then calling `Encode::decode()` when using the value of `$File::Find::name`:

```
my $path = Encode::decode('utf8', $File::Find::name);
```

To be more clear, this is how `$File::Find::name` was formed:

```
use Encode;

# This is a way to get $dir to be represented as a UTF-8 string

my $dir = 'L' .chr(233).'o'.chr(256);
chop $dir;

say "dir: ", d($dir); # length = 3

# This is what readdir() is returning:

my $leaf = encode('utf8', 'Lakem' . chr(233));

say "leaf: ", d($leaf); # length = 7

$File::Find::name = $dir . '/' . $leaf;

say "File::Find::name: ", d($File::Find::name);

sub d {
  join(' ', map { sprintf("%02X", ord($_)) } split('', $_[0]))
}
```

Comment: Work the file test operators like `-f` with decoded or encoded file names?

Comment: The file test operators also need octets

Answer (score -2):

The POSIX filesystem API is broken as no encoding is enforced. Period.

Many problems can happen. For example a pathname can even contain both latin1 and UTF-8 depending on how various filesystems on a path handle encoding (and if they do).