# Which operators and functions expect their string arguments as octets?

Tags: perl, function, unicode, encoding, operators

Does somewhere exist a list with all Perl operators and functions which expect their string arguments as octets?

For example the file test operators need octets ( [Question about pathname encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546341/question-about-pathname-encoding) comment ).

Now I found a code with `symlink` and I am not sure if I should encode the file names.

Comment: do you have any example, so people will know what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s simply because the traditional Unix syscalls that Perl either uses or emulates are all  defined in terms of bytes, not characters.  If you want a UTF-8 encoded or decoded filename, then you have to do that for yourself. You will not get what you want if you do not.

Comment: it feels weird - I've never seen a code like this `open my $fh, '>', encode( 'utf8', 'my_filename' )`

Comment: sid_com: Hardcoding the FS encoding results in highly system-specific code. Factor this out to make it portable, and use PerlIO::fse to detect the encoding.